# Logstash: How to use JSON record IP information in the output plugin?

Tags: logstash

The JSON file has multiple records, each record contains an IP field.

```
{"ip":"1.1.1.1","25":"smtp"}
{"ip":"1.1.1.1","80":"http"}
```

When log stash sending data to elastic search,I want to know How to use JSON IP field value as elastic search ID,how should I write the output section of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute in the elasticsearch output plugin where you can specify the document id of your choice. You can assign the value of one of your fields to document id as follows:

```
output {
       elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
          document_id => "%{ip}"
       }
}
```

This will work provided your input plugin and filter plugin are working correctly creating a field `ip`.

For reference [Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id)